# How do I install the USB drivers for my Phone?

Tags: android, usb, driver, windows-10, huawei-mobile-services

Hi I have a problem recognizing the USB driver.

My mobile phone: HUAWEI Honor 4C
My laptop Windows: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit

> USB Driver: https://androidmtk.com/download-huawei-usb-drivers
>
> Android ADB: http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

I have trouble installing Windows Me driver sent and received no hardware drivers will not install on any phone. I had this problem before, but suddenly this problem has arisen.

I can not I install drivers for USB Driver ADB and nothing happens when I install.

It seems that my Windows is corrupted what should I do?

Unfortunately, my English is very bad. This is Google Translate. Excuse me.

Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows 10 will not install drivers which are not digitally signed. You need to Disable Driver Signature Verification.

Follow steps carefully:

1. Press SHIFT + Restart button from Power Menu
2. In Troubleshoot Menu, Click on Troubleshoot
3. Then Click on Advanced options
4. In Advanced Option, Click on Startup Settings
5. Then click Restart button on bottom left
6. You will be then showed Startup Setting option
7. Press F7 to enter Disable Driver Signature Enforcement

It will take you on your normal Desktop. Then install your mobile driver as suggested on Android ADB website.

Comment: Thanks.
I've done it before, but still not installed.
After installing the drivers and nothing happens.

Comment: Is the version of ADB Driver Installer is 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy! When you connect your Android phone to a Windows 10 computer, Windows system will help you install the driver automatically. If it can't install successfully, you can install in device manager. Another way is to use driver tool like **Driver Talent** to help you install android phone driver on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late. 
Some android phones come with the drivers in the phone, so you may not need to download one. 
Connect your phone via USB, under the usb options(i.e the place where you select usb storage, media device, charge only.....),  select usb virtual drive

On your computer's file Explorer (in windows), you should see the phone as a drive usually(mine shows "CD Drive(E:)" 
Open the drive and the open(unzip)  the "driver coding"  folder and select either the 32 or a 64 bit install. 
That was how I solved mine.
 Hope it works 4 u guys too.